# How to pass Authorization header in reactjs API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64, authorization

```
module.exports ={

_callAPI: function(url,method,data,target){
    let  token = "santhi" + ":" + "santhi";
    let  hash = btoa(token);
    console.log(hash);
    $.ajax({
        url: BASEURL + url,
        method: method,
        data: data,
        processData: true,
        dataType: 'json',
         headers: {
        "Authorization" :"Basic " + hash,
        "Content-Type" :"application/json"
        },

        success: (data,textStatus, jqXHR) => {
            target('success', data);            
        },
        error: (jqXhr,textStatus,error) => {
            target('error',jqXhr,textStatus,error);
        }
    });
},
```

}

I am adding authorization as headers like thing. but i am not getting anything. Is there any other way to authorize base64 encoding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your server output? The way you pass authorization header is correct

Comment: i have edited the quetion can you check whether it is right?

Comment: 401 unauthorized was the output options call alone getting called instead of GET method,

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8014' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Comment: You need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with the origin of the request as value to the response message